# Loop over an associative array and use the values for another action?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, imagemagick, associative-array

First time writing a bash script. I'm just piece mealing examples I've found from stackoverflow questions.

**Question:**  How can I combine the assoicated array declared `imagetable` and the resize script, so that it will loop the action based on the keys values.

Associative Array:

```
declare -A imagetable
imagetable=(
    ["custom-insights-laptop_1x.png"]   937x508
    ["custom-insights-laptop_2x.png"]   1874x1015
)
```

**resize script**

```
#!/bin/bash

#replace this -name value from imagetable
RETINA_IMAGES=`find . -name "custom-insights-laptop_1x.png"`

for retina_path in $RETINA_IMAGES
do
  target_path="${retina_path%.png}.png"

  #replace the -resize value from imagetable.
  convert -resize 937x508 $retina_path $target_path 

  echo "Converted ${retina_path} to ${target_path}"
done
```

Comment: I'm surprised that your assignment code even works. Are you really using bash? Because the `imagetable` assignment is a syntax error and should give you "must use subscript when assigning associative array" errors when you execute it. You need `["custom-insights-laptop_1x.png"]="937x508"` instead of `["custom-insights-laptop_1x.png"]   "937x508"`, for instance. The only explanation I can find is that you didn't really execute `declare -A imagetable`, so you ended up with a regular indexed array.

Comment: All of the above is true, but  your problem would be more manageable if you reduced the number of "array" elements you posted in your code. We don't really need to see the whole thing to help. While `//` may work as a comment in non-working code, use the standard `#` char and avoid a whole class of undecipherable error messages ;-) AND .. You have embedded comments that seem to be questions, but its not really clear what your problem is. Do you want us to cut/paste your code and debug it for you?

Comment: Sorry I come from javascript :( I'll fix the question.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the critque does the question make more sense?

Comment: Matthew : Less is more! I've got to walk my neighbors dog. Hopefully I can come back and look at your problem  ;-). OR did you try 4ae1e1 's suggestions, I think they are on target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your need, but I'm unclear on your `RETINA_IMAGES=$(find .. )`

This much is sure to help you.

```
declare -A imagetable
imagetable=(
    [custom-insights-laptop_1x.png]=937x508
    [custom-insights-laptop_2x.png]=1874x1015
)

for i in ${!imagetable[*]} ; do
   echo "#dbg: i = $i and \${imagetable[$i]}=${imagetable[$i]}"

   sz=${imagetable[$i]}
   convert -resize "${sz}" "$retina_path" "$target_path"
done
```

Avoid a whole class of shell scripting errors by dbl-quoting uses of variables as I have done on the convert line.

If you need further help, leave a comment.

You can learn a lot about assoc arrays just by doing

```
echo ${!arr[*]} 
echo ${arr[*]}
echo ${#arr[*]}
echo ${arr[key]}
```

**edit**

so to go a step further,  there is no need to save filenames as RETINA_IMAGES (Thanks @MarkSetchell, I get it now ;-)

Try something like

```
fileTarget="custom-insights-laptop_1x.png"
find . -name "$fileTarget" \
| while read retina_path ; do
  target_path="${retina_path%.png}.png"

  #replace the -resize value from imagetable.
  convert -resize ${imagetable[$fileTarget]} $retina_path $target_path 

  echo "Converted ${retina_path} to ${target_path}"
done
```

You can then make a for-loop of all your ${!imagetable[*]} values, that sets `$fileTarget`.

IHTH

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go - nice answer. I think the `find` is (rightly) in there because OP has images with same name in multiple directories and he wants to resize them all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need some code help, this seems easiest, and you won't need an associative array:

```
imgfile[0]="fileA.png"
imgfile[1]="fileB.png"
imgfile[2]="fileC.png"

for f in ${imgfile[@]}
do
    IMGSET=$(find . -name "$f")
    #other iterative code here
done
```